# Migrating from AtMega328 to AtMega644p

Tags: c, embedded, avr, cpu-registers, atmega

I have a robot which used a AtMega 328/L 40pin until recently when I needed more resources, so I moved to the Atmega 644p.

The registers and bit names are different between the two and to be honest I just cannot get the new one to work properly.  I am certain I have followed the changes as stated in the datasheet, but feel that my lack of knowledge in standing in the way.

Here is the 328 function that did work:

```
{
portInit();     // Setup port directions and initial values.
                // This is the most important step!

cli();          // Disable global interrupts.

// UART:
UBRRH = UBRR_BAUD_LOW >> 8; // Setup UART: Baud is Low Speed
UBRRL = (uint8_t) UBRR_BAUD_LOW;
UCSRA = 0x00;
     UCSRC = (1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0);
     UCSRB = (1 << TXEN) | (1 << RXEN) | (1 << RXCIE);

// Initialize ADC:
ADMUX = 0; //external reference 
ADCSRA = (0<<ADIE) | (0<<ADEN) | (1<<ADPS2) | (1<<ADPS1) | (1<<ADIF);
SFIOR = 0;

// Initialize External interrupts - all disabled:
MCUCR = (1 << ISC11) | (1 << ISC10) | (1 << ISC01) | (1 << ISC00);
GICR = (0 << INT2) | (0 << INT1) | (0 << INT0);
MCUCSR = (0 << ISC2);


// 10kHz Timer 0:
TCCR0 =   (0 << WGM00) 
        | (1 << WGM01) 
        | (0 << COM00) 
        | (0 << COM01) 
        | (0 << CS02)  
        | (1 << CS01) 
        | (0 << CS00);
OCR0  = 199;


//Timer 1 is free for your application!


// Timer 2 - used for beeper:
TCCR2 =  0; 
OCR2  = 0xFF; 

// Enable timer interrupts:
TIMSK =   (1 << OCIE0); 

sei(); // Enable Global Interrupts
}
```

And here is the code I am trying to get working:

```
{
portInit();     // Setup port directions and initial values.
                // This is the most important step!


cli();          // Disable global interrupts.


     // UART:
//UBRRH = UBRR_BAUD_LOW >> 8;   // Setup UART: Baud is Low Speed
//UBRR0L = (uint8_t) UBRR_BAUD_LOW;
//UCSR0A = 0x00;
     //UCSR0C = ((1<<UCSZ00));
     //UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);

// Initialize ADC:
ADMUX = 0; //external reference 
ADCSRA = (0<<ADIE) | (0<<ADEN) | (1<<ADPS2) | (1<<ADPS1) | (1<<ADIF);
ADCSRB = 0;

// Initialize External interrupts - all disabled:
//MCUCR 
SMCR = (1 << ISC11) | (1 << ISC10) | (1 << ISC01) | (1 << ISC00);
EIMSK = (0 << INT2) | (0 << INT1) | (0 << INT0);
MCUSR = (0 << ISC20);


// 10kHz Timer 0:
TCCR0A =   (0 << WGM00) 
        | (1 << WGM01) 
        | (0 << COM0A0) 
        | (0 << COM0A1);

TCCR0B = (0 << CS02)  
        | (1 << CS01) 
        | (0 << CS00);
OCR0A  = 199;
/*
Timer 1 is free for your application!
*/

// Timer 2 - used for beeper:
TCCR2A =  0; 
OCR2A  = 0xFF; 

// Enable timer interrupts:
TIMSK0 =   (1 << OCIE0A); 

sei(); // Enable Global Interrupts
}
```

I have never worked with these before so I am trying my best.

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong here?

Kind Regards
Lee

Comment: What doesn't work about it and how do you know/what do you look for to know that it does not work? Have you tried a completely fresh test project where you just set up the peripheral you want to use so you can figure out how it is supposed to be set up? PS, I added the embedded tag.

Comment: hi tinman, I have literally just put the chip in and then tried it, I belive my problems are related to the tmer, as a timed beeper i use crashes each time its used. plus it doesn't like the TWI any more.  Iwill try a fresh test on breadboard.  I know its running cause i have some leds flashing but nothing else will work, just stops.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a new software project rather than a new board. Then just try to concentrate on getting e.g. timer 2 working. Your question is quite large, covering all the peripherals you use, and leaves out lots of information. For example, you have timer 2 running but don't seem to have it driving an output and it doesn't look like it's interrupt is used. So the problem code with that may be somewhere else. If you can reduce it to getting an understanding of a single peripheral you'll have more complete code that can be posted and asked about here.

Comment: [SOLVED] I must have been reading the datasheet upside down or something!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it fixed. You should post your solution as an answer and accept it, so that your question appears as answered and solved, and it may help future readers. You can do that here but I think there are time limits between asking a question and answering it yourself.

Comment: @user1167501, it is often of value to others to post what you missed or maybe some explanation of what went wrong. Also, electronics.stackexchange.com is a good home for this type of question.

Comment: O.K, I apologise for not adding it yet!  Its just I am stuck on a final year project so really busy.  I will add this information when I get 30mins...  Thanks for the help!